# Remoting in .net

Tags: c#, remoting

I am doing applications on .net remoting ,i write the code for

```
       Client -----------> server
```

but

```
       client <------------ server
```

i don't know how to do it(just like a chat),Please give suggestions and some samples to look up.

```
   without any request from server i send messages from my client application
```

Comment: if the "client" can receive calls from the server, and act upon them, without having requested anything on their own, i believe the client is, by definition, a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [MarshalByRefObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject(VS.71).aspx) and events.  This would allow the Server to respond back to the client.

[Here is a sample on code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Chat_Application.aspx)

[Another Sample with Event CallBack](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/TwoWayRemoting.aspx)

Comment: you should know, that another connection from server to client will automatically be established.